# Leaflet MarkerCluster and customized markers

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I' trying to implement a Leaflet map with the plugin MarkerCluster and customized marker icons. The code works well in rendering the clusters but I've some problems with the markers. Indeed the markers rendered are the classical leaflet blue-colored pins instead of my customized icons (ie logo_circle.png)
Here is the code:

```
var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            maxZoom: 18
            }),
            latlng = L.latLng(37.366667, 128.4);

        var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 9, layers: [tiles]});


        var OlympicIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'logo_circle.png',
            iconSize:     [36, 36], // size of the icon
            iconAnchor:   [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            popupAnchor:  [0, 0] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        });


        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

        for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
            var a = addressPoints[i];
            var title = a[2];
            var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title }, {icon: myIcon});
            marker.bindPopup(title);
            markers.addLayer(marker);
        }

        markers.addLayer(OlympicIcon);

        map.addLayer(markers);
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `icon` option should simply be a *member* of the 2nd argument (options) of `L.marker` factory, alongside `title` option, instead of being a separate 3rd argument:

```js
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
  title: title,
  icon: myIcon
});
```

See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183725/leaflet-pop-up-does-not-work-with-geojson-data/183832#183832